# Is it possible to keep files in glacier after deletion from s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, whm, amazon-glacier

Is it possible to move or copy files from s3 to glacier (or if not possible another cheaper storage class) although the original s3 files will be deleted? Looking for a robust solution for server backups from whm > s3 > glacier. I've trialled multiple lifecycle rules, and can see several questions have been asked around this here, but I can't seem to get the settings right.

WHM sends backups to s3 fine for me. It works by essentially creating a mirror of the on-server backups on s3. My problem is that the way the whm/s3 integration works means that when the on-server backups are deleted at the end of the month so are the backups in the s3 bucket.

What I'd like to achieve is that before the files are deleted from s3 they're permanently kept for a specified period, say 6 months. I've tried rules to archive them to glacier without success and *think* this is because the original files are deleted and so are the glacier instances?

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two ways to use Amazon Glacier:

- As an Amazon S3 storage class (as you describe), or
- By interacting with Amazon Glacier directly

Amazon Glacier has its own API that you can use to upload/download objects to/from a Glacier vault (which is the equivalent to an S3 bucket). In fact, when you use Amazon S3 to move data into Glacier, S3 is simply calling the standard Glacier API to send the data to Glacier. The difference is that S3 is managing the vault for you, so you own't see the objects listed in your Glacier console.

So, what you might choose to do is:

- Create your WHM backups
- Send them directly to Glacier

**Versioning**

An alternative approach is to use **Amazon S3 Versioning**. This means that objects delete from Amazon S3 are not actually deleted. Rather, a *delete marker* hides the object, but the object is still accessible.

You could then define a lifecycle policy to delete non-current versions (including deleted objects) after a period of time.

See (old article): [Amazon S3 Lifecycle Management for Versioned Objects | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-lifecycle-management-update/)

Comment: Ignore my response. After re-reading the question, I realized OP wants to remove from S3 after 6 months, not remove the files entirely.

Comment: Thanks John, that clarifies for me the differences. I'm still struggling with the lifecycle policy setup, can see the delete markers but can't seem to access the files. Will give it another shot.

Comment: Tip: In the console, if you have versioning enabled you should see a Show/Hide button. It will then show all versions, including _Delete Marker_.

Comment: I'm getting closer but still haven't cracked it.

So on the 1st of each month backup files are sent to my s3 bucket.
Directory structure sent is: monthly/yyyy-mm-dd/accounts/files. 
After this the WHM/cPanel system automatically deletes the previous month's directory. 

Is this the correct lifecycle policy?
Name and scope: filter: prefix monthly
Transitions: Current version: Transition to Amazon Glacier after 27 days
Expiration: Previous versions: Permanently delete previous versions after 180 days

(No direct to glacier option unfortunately)

Thanks.